# Evaluate $\int_{y=-\infty}^1\int_{x=0}^\infty 4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{y=-\infty}^1\int_{x=0}^\infty 4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

I tried to solve this for hours without any success. I tried substitution method of $u = x^2+y^2$ but doesn't seem to work.

Here is my attempt:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^1\int_0^\infty (16x^2y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^2 + y^2)^\frac{1}{2} \; \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}{y} = \int_{-\infty}^1 \int_0^\infty (16x^3y^2 + 16x^2 y^3)^{\frac{1}{2}} \; \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}{y}.$$
> Let
> \begin{align}
> u &= 16x^3 y^2 + 16x^2 y^3 \\
> \mathrm{d}u &= (48x^2y^2 + 32xy^3) \; \mathrm{d}{x} \\
> \mathrm{d}u &= 16xy^2(3x + 2y) \; \mathrm{d}{x} \\
> \mathrm{d}u &= 4xy(12xy + 8y^2) \; \mathrm{d}{x} \\
> 4xy \; \mathrm{d}{x} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}{u}}{12xy + 8y^2}.
> \end{align}
> $$\int_{-\infty}^1 \int_0^\infty 4xy \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_{-\infty}^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(12xy + 8y^2)}.$$

Attaching image for reference

[image]

---

**EDITS**

Original Post asked `integrate: 4xy sqrt(x^2+y^2) where 0<x, y<1`, and added this image. [image].
Later edits misread `0<x,y<1` as if `0<x<1`and `0<y<1`

Comment: These new limits of integration can't be right.  The integral obviously diverges.  The problem was originally written asking for the integral over the unit square (in the first quadrant), and I think that's what was intended.

Comment: @RobertShore that was the integral in the linked image.

Comment: The original image for reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Gyt.gif

Comment: @RobertShore What new limits of integration? If you check the edit history, the OP originally posted a linked image, which gave the limits of integration in the newest version. It wasn't changed.

Comment: The original post (which didn't use MathJax) also stated the limits of integration as $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$.

Comment: ...yes, so what's the issue, exactly?

Comment: Oh I see, you're interpreting **both** $x,y$ as being in $[0,1]$. I assumed it was just a list of conditions, i.e. $0 < x$ and $y < 1$. Plus the integral included with the OP at the time actually reflected this latter interpretation.

Comment: That was my edit.  Not certain that’s what the OP intended, but based on the math I think it’s likely.  Need clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first integrate with respect to $x$ while treating $y$ as a constant. Then, you integrate the result of that with respect to $y$:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} 4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{4}{2}y\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\right)\,dy=
\int_{0}^{1}\left(2y\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,d(x^2+y^2)\right)\,dy=\\
\int_{0}^{1}\left(2y\frac{2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}{3}\bigg|_{0}^{1}\right)\,dy=
\int_{0}^{1}\left[2y\left(\frac{2\sqrt{(1^2+y^2)^3}}{3}-\frac{2\sqrt{(0^2+y^2)^3}}{3}\right)\right]\,dy=\\
\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\left(y\sqrt{(1+y^2)^3}-y^4\right)\,dy=\\
\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{1}y\sqrt{(1+y^2)^3}\,dy-\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{1}y^4\,dy=\\
\frac{4/3}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(1+y^2)^3}\frac{d}{dy}(1+y^2)\,dy-\frac{4}{3}\frac{y^5}{5}\bigg|_{0}^{1}=\\
\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}(1+y^2)^{3/2}\,d(1+y^2)-\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1^5}{5}-\frac{0^5}{5}\right)=\\
\frac{2}{3}\frac{2(1+y^2)^{5/2}}{5}\bigg|_{0}^{1}-\frac{4}{15}=\\
\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2(1+1^2)^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{2(1+0^2)^{5/2}}{5}\right)-\frac{4}{15}=\\
\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2^5}}{5}-\frac{2}{5}\right)-\frac{4}{15}=\\
\frac{4(4\sqrt{2}-1)}{15}-\frac{4}{15}=\frac{16\sqrt{2}-4-4}{15}=\frac{16(\sqrt{2}-8)}{15}=\frac{8(2\sqrt{2}-1)}{15}.
$$

[Wolfram Alpha check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(integrate%204xy*sqrt(x%5E2%2By%5E2)dx%20from%200%20to%201)%20dy%20from%200%20to%201).

Answer (score 2):

With constant $y$ the substitution $u=x^2+y^2$ implies $$\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2}xdx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{y^2}^{1+y^2}u^{1/2}du=\frac{1}{3}[u^{3/2}]_{y^2}^{1+y^2}=\frac{(1+y^2)^{3/2}-y^3}{3}.$$Now we apply the integration operator $4\int_0^1 dy\,y$, giving$$\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1[y(1+y^2)^{3/2}-y^4]dy=\frac{4}{15}[(1+y^2)^{5/2}-y^5]_0^1=\frac{4}{15}(2^{5/2}-2)\approx 0.975.$$

Comment: how did you change the upper and lower limit from 0 to 1, to y^2 to 1+y^2, I understand the rest of the solution. Thank you

Comment: @Nawa From $u=x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this a piece at a time.  First compute the inner integral with respect to $y$ (considering $x$ to be a constant for the moment).  Do you see how to do that via the obvious $u$-substitution that you've already considered?

Once you have computed that integral (which will result in some expression that's a function of $x$), compute the outer integral with respect to $x$.

Let us know if you're still stuck.

Comment: Still Stuck, :(

Comment: If I could upload an image as a comment I would have shown you how many pages I practiced trying to solve it....

Comment: Please clarify the intended limits of integration and edit your posts to show some of your work.

Comment: Here is my attempt

Comment: Try $u = x^2+y^2$ and don't move anything inside the radical.

Comment: I tried with u substitution but end up with wrong answer, I am pretty sure I did something wrong on this. Please let me know if you can. Answer is supposed to be 0.975

Comment: Please double check your limits of integration.  I'm pretty sure the improper integral written above diverges.

Comment: I double and triple checked, that's the correct limit. This problem is directly from the Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists Ninth edition by Walpole

Comment: The integrand is an odd function in $y$ so you can change the $y$ limits to $- \infty$ and $-1$ (the integral from $-1$ to $1$ will always be $0$) but I don't see how that helps you.  I don't usually encourage this, but maybe it's a good idea for you to post a picture of the problem directly from the book.  Because those limits of integration can't possibly be right.  If the result converges (and I'm pretty sure it doesn't), it *has* to be negative because the integrand is negative whenever $y \leq -1$.

Comment: @ Robert Shore My assumption was wrong on the upper limit and lower limit, I changed the question accordingly. I know how to do the integration but I just need to understand the u substitution method to solve the sqrt.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Don't switch to polar coordinates. Notice that

$$\frac d{dx}(x^2+y^2)^a=2ax(x^2+y^2)^{a-1}$$

and

$$\frac d{dy}\frac d{dx}2ax(x^2+y^2)^{a-1}=4a(a-1)xy(x^2+y^2)^{a-2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates, the integrand is

$$4\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\,\rho\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta.$$

By symmetry, we can integrate twice in the triangle between $\theta=0,\theta=\dfrac\pi4$ and $\rho\cos\theta=1$ (or $\rho=\dfrac1{\cos\theta}$).

After integration on $\rho$,

$$8\cos\theta\sin\theta\ \left.\frac{4\rho^5}{5}\right|_0^{1/\cos\theta}=\frac{32}5\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^4\theta}.$$

Then

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^4\theta}\,d\theta=\int_0^{1/\sqrt2}\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^2}\,d\theta.$$

This integral is soluble by decomposition in simple fractions.